# Add Android Studio project to github repository within organization

Tags: android, android-studio, github, github-organizations

I am interested in uploading my Android studio project to a Github repository that already exists within an organization. When I tried to do this directly through Android Studio, I was able to make a brand new repository with all of the files successfully, but it is not within the organization as desired. There are already files on the organization repository that are part of the project, but not part of the Android Studio development, so I need to be able to upload my files directly to that repository. Is that possible? How can I do that directly from Android Studio?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.